# Python hex from socket converts to ascii

Tags: python, sockets

I am sure there is a simple answer to this, the problem is phrasing it correctly in google to get the answer which I can seem to do. I am getting a raw packet from a socket.

```
pkt=sock.recv(2048)
'\x00\x00\x12\x00.H\x00\x00\x00\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xb3\x01\x00\x00'
```

The above is the radiotap as you can see, several of the bytes were converted to ascii namely '.', 'H', 't'. How can I get the hex values so it reads:

```
'\x00\x00\x12\x00\x2e\x48 ...'
```

Comment: I don't think the bytes were actually converted to ASCII; rather the print routine is displaying printable byte values as ascii characters.

Comment: I don't think so either but I would like to see it print out that way on the screen

Answer (score 2):

Since recv() returns a string you could do something like this:

```
pkt=sock.recv(2048)
# pkt = "1234567890" # uncomment to test

for i in pkt:
    print hex(ord(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically use something like the following when displaying strings in hex form:

```
>>> def tohexstr(s):
...     return ''.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
...
>>> tohexstr('1 2 3 a b c')
'3120322033206120622063'
```

If you're doing this a lot, you might like to subclass `str` and override the `__repr__` method:

```
>>> class hexstr(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return ''.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in self)
...
>>> hexstr('\x01\x02\x03\x30\x31abc')
0102033031616263
```

Play around with different byte separators to see what works for you, eg:

```
>>> s = 'abc123'
>>> print ''.join('\\x%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
\x61\x62\x63\x31\x32\x33
>>> print '-'.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
61-62-63-31-32-33
```

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is just a readable string representation. In reality, `\x00` is one byte, the null byte. `H` is one byte as well, it has the value 0x48 (as you already wrote).

If you print that string immediately, you'll only see the printable characters; che control characters will be executed.

If you want a full valued hex representation, you might want to do

```
print pkt.encode('hex') # at least under Py2
print " ".join("%02x" % ord(i) for i in pkt)
print "\x" + "\x".join("%02x" % ord(i) for i in pkt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think those are the numbers you are getting. Note:

```
In [24]: aaa =  '\x00\x00\x12\x00\x2E\x48\x00\x02'

In [25]: aaa
Out[25]: '\x00\x00\x12\x00.H\x00\x02'
```